# fork() and how signals are delivered to processes

Tags: process, signals, fork

I program that I wrote in C fork()'s off a child process. Neither process will terminate. If I launch the program from the command line and press control-c which process(es) will receive the interrupt signal?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why don't we try it out and see? Here's a trivial program using [`signal(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) to trap `SIGINT` in both the parent and child process and print out a message identifying the process when it arrives.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
void parent_trap(int sig) {fprintf(stderr, "They got back together!\n");}
void child_trap(int sig) {fprintf(stderr, "Caught signal in CHILD.\n");}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (!fork()) {
        signal(SIGINT, &child_trap);
        sleep(1000);
        exit(0);
    }
    signal(SIGINT, &parent_trap);
    sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Let's call that `test.c`. Now we can run it:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
^CCaught signal in CHILD.
They got back together!
```

**Interrupt signals generated in the terminal are delivered to the active process group, which here includes both parent and child**. You can see that both `child_trap` and [`parent_trap`](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055277/) were executed when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

There is a [lengthy discussion of interactions between `fork` and signals in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html#tag_03_177_08). The most material part of it here is that:

> A signal sent to the process group after the fork() should be delivered to both parent and child.

They also note that some systems may not behave in exactly the correct way, in particular when the signal arrives very close to the time of the `fork()`. Figuring out whether you're on one of those systems is probably going to require reading the code or a lot of luck, because the interactions are vanishingly unlikely in each individual attempt.

Other useful points are that:

- A signal manually generated and sent to an individual process (perhaps with [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html)) will be delivered *only* to that process, regardless of whether it is the parent or child.
- The order that the signal handlers run between processes is not defined, so you can't rely on either executing first.
- If you *don't* define an interrupt handler (or explicitly ignore the signal), both processes would just exit with a `SIGINT` code (the default behaviour).
- If one handles the signal non-fatally and the other doesn't, the one without the handler will die and the other will continue.

Comment: I assume shells can also interfere in interesting ways? If it is a signal that they can trap, it might send it to its children? (And then there is SIGHUP) (All of this might mean that while the OS does not send the signals, a child process might not be unaffected by a signal to the parent...)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg child processes spawned by a shell script will receive a signal even if you trap that signal in the  shell script, as **Interrupt signals generated in the terminal are delivered to the active process group, which here includes both parent and child**.
You can inspect the process group of a process with `ps` as in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82724/ps-arguments-to-display-pid-ppid-pgid-and-sid-collectively